# RESTful HTML page

Tags: html, web-services, rest, get, separation-of-concerns

My understanding of web services is that they are used to provide distributable functionality. However, as RESTful web services can return HTML and show this HTML as a regular web page in the browser, we then have a view rather than business logic. Is this ever useful or is it a violation of the separation of concern principle?

Comment: Believe it or not, HTML was not designed to be a view.  HTML is supposed to be content.  Standard HTML based web sites can completely conform to all REST constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing something here.

REST is a web api design model and thus focuses on the integration of different applications rather than the internal structure of those.

That being said, REST is a very relaxed model. However the corner stones of a rest system are:

**Its state less**

You do not have some kind of a session like with soap, where you first authenticate and then get a session id and can perform actions. In rest every call is independent and has all the data/information needed to be processed and does not rely upon any preceeding or sucessing calls

**every service is uniquely adressable by a uri**

**there are oprations that must meet certain criteria**

for example a simple web server usually servers GET requests, those must be `safe`, meaning they will not modify anything, they are read only

here is a good article...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/253944/Representational-State-Transfer-A-Short-Walkthroug

Comment: Thank you but I fail to see how this is relevant. I use a get request on a RESTful service which returns HTML, following this tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipzz.html

By having the resource as the startup page, it shows the HTML as if it were a normal HTML page. That's what I find confusing.

Comment: ok, as soon as java is involved i will exercise my right to remain silent ;) ideologies and definitions tend to collide here.

Comment: alright! thanks for the article, though -- an interesting one.